# How can I change the color of a BitMapFont that is already generated by FreeTypeFontGenerator in render

Tags: libgdx, graphic-effects, fonts

I'm trying to make a start loading screen with Fade In effect.
I've made a simple Animation generator and it works fine when I apply the alpha value for the sprite
,but when I try to apply the same alpha for a bitmapfont which is generated from a ttf file, the setColor won't affect the color of bitmap font. am I missing something or this is a bug/feature?
here is my code:

**generating font**:

```
parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.characters=generator.DEFAULT_CHARS;
parameter.color= new Color(70f/255f,40f/255f,190f/255f,1);
parameter.shadowColor=parameter.borderColor= new Color(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);
parameter.shadowOffsetX=6;
parameter.shadowOffsetY=6;
parameter.size=100;
        
generator= new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("type_tahrir.ttf"));
font=generator.generateFont(parameter);
layout= new GlyphLayout(font,"Void Studio");
```

**rendering font and sprite:**

```
@Override
public void render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
 
    Gdx.gl.glClear(Gdx.gl20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    deltaTime= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
 
    alpha=logoAnimation.update(deltaTime).alpha;
        
    camera.update();
        
    logoSprite.setAlpha(alpha);
 
    font.setColor(70f/255f,40f/255f,190f/255f,alpha);
         
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    logoSprite.draw(batch);
    font.draw(batch,layout,1000-layout.width/2,300);
    batch.end();
}
```

**TL;DR** is it possible to change color of bitmap font after being generated via FreeType

Info: libgdx and gdx-freetype version 1.9.0